# what is the filter logic behind delegated tasks filter

Tags: apex, tasks

I want to know about the filter logic of delegated tasks?

**Requirement:**
I need to show the list of delegated tasks in my custom visual force page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the filter is simply `CreatedById != OwnerId && CreatedById = :UserInfo.getUserId()`, which isn't something you can currently replicate in SOQL without a formula field.